# SpringBoot works from IntelliJ but throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError from JAR

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, kotlin, corda, activemq-artemis

I am building a SpringBoot REST client that hooks into a CorDapp (Corda Application) via RPC. The RPC proxy has a dependency on ActiveMQ/Artemis.

My gradle.build file contains these dependencies

```
compile "org.apache.activemq:artemis-commons:$active_mq_version"
compile "org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client:$active_mq_version"
```

When I run the application from IntelliJ, everything works fine.

The module and all its dependencies are Fat-JAR'd into a stand-alone JAR file using the following gradle task

```
jar {
    zip64 = true
    from {
        String[] include = [
                "kotlin-runtime-${kotlin_version}.jar",
                "kotlin-stdlib-${kotlin_version}.jar"
        ]

        configurations.compile
                .findAll { include.contains(it.name) }
                .collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'com.client.ApplicationKt'
        )
    }
}
```

When I try to run the JAR file, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientSession.createTemporaryQueue(Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/SimpleString;Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/RoutingType;Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/SimpleString;)

When I inspect the contents of the JAR file, it appears that ActiveMQ/Artemis has been Fat-JAR'd correctly, so I'm not sure why it can't find the method?

Comment: Because you are trying to out smart and work around Spring Boot. You have to use the Spring Boot plugin to crate a executable jar don't try to do it yourself. Spring Boot requires a specific layout of the jar file which is all embedded in the spring boot plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a fat jar like that when working with spring boot.
You can include the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin) to your build.gradle.

Then, simply running a gradle build will generate a spring boot jar file in the `target` folder which will have all required dependencies and can be run with a `java -jar`.

More Info here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#_jar_support_and_groovy_support